# MPI job stopped with ssh disconnected

Tags: ssh, mpi

I have been using MPI in THCP diskless sever.
However, when I run jobs with MPI, sometimes the process die because of SSH disconnected.

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

There is no error or no error in a single job.
Also if I tried to connect with SSH for each CPU after the job die, it connected normally

My source code use INTEL MKL library and server is composed with 16 cpus of AMD Ryzen 9 5900x  and 48GB RAM memory, also I use MPICH3.

How can I solve this problem?
Is there a way to find the error log related to sshd disconnection uncertaintly?

Thank you.

Comment: A/ are you running systemd ? (is the journalctl utility available) ? B/ Is your diskless server /var/log directory mounted on tmpfs ? C/ (not immediately related) do all of your CPUs belong to the same NUMA node ?

Comment: Sorry for late response. 1. Yes, I can use journalctl 2. my diskless server mounted on /tftpboot/ (I created tftpboot directory in root) 3. I don't know NUMA, I just can access with SSH. Also, I use fedora35

Comment: I suspect this to be caused by SSH Connection Timeout on server side. Check and if possible increase it : https://linuxhint.com/increase-ssh-connection-timeout/ On a side note, if all your cpus belong to the same numa node (let"s quickly say same hardware system) it's highly probable that MPI just don't bring any performance advantage.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already checked the SSH setting by searching the web, but there was no difference. The symptom is different with other postings, in my case most of the connection error with MPI comes with memory leak, complicated simulations and etc. 
Anyway, I just use MPI for running parallel job (with same parameter setting) for Monte Carlo simulation, so I don't care about performance advantage, but thanks again for your comment.